# Using Virtualbox within Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-machine, virtualbox

We want to demo one of our Android system, in a virtual world using Unity. We would want to use for example a Virtualbox to simulate our virtual system, and show its display on Unity.

We would also want that Android device to be able to connect to an outside internet service exactly like a real physical Android device would do.

Is this doable, and if yes, how can this be done using Unity and Virtualbox?

Comment: Have you just tried it.  VirtualBox is pretty good at detecting and setting up a wired connection.  Never tried using Unity in it though.  I can imagine this would kill you though.

Comment: I'd guess only with an incredibly massive amount of work.  You'd have to do something like create your own video and keyboard drivers for virtualbox that instead of using the real hardware sends / receives to Unity.  Another very difficult idea would be re-writing some open source screen sharing or remote desktop package so that Unity is one end of the connection.  This is not a weekend job!

Comment: I assume the Android app is not already a Unity app?  Otherwise it'd be really simple...